# Google play like slider for ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im trying to create a uiview horizontal touch slider. Similar to how the google page store is designed on android. I was thinking i would just put a bunch of uiviews (as pages) inside a single huge uiview and just drag the uiview along on touchevent. But i also need to detech which is the active view to perform post requests and itd need to loop. Any suggestions? Tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

I think the appropriate answer for your question would be "Horizontal UITableView". Checkout these code shared on GitHub.

[EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView)

[Another Example for Horizontal Table View](https://github.com/rickharrison/RHHorizontalTableView)

You can design cells as per your need to show. Also you will get each active cell when you click it in didSelectRow.

Hope it works for you.